# mongodb - Construct DBRef with string or ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, objectid, dbref

I've noticed that either a string or an object id could be used to construct a `DBRef` in mongodb. For example

```
db.persons.insert({name: 'alice'})
db.persons.find()
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5165419064fada69cef33ea2"), "name" : "alice" }
db.persons.insert({name: 'bob', sister: new DBRef('persons', '5165419064fada69cef33ea2')}) // use a string
db.persons.find()
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5165419064fada69cef33ea2"), "name" : "alice" }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("516541c064fada69cef33ea3"), "name" : "bob", "sister" : { "$ref" : "persons", "$id" : "5165419064fada69cef33ea2" } }
db.persons.insert({name: 'cavin', sister: new DBRef('persons', new ObjectId('5165419064fada69cef33ea2'))}) // use an ObjectId
db.persons.find()
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5165419064fada69cef33ea2"), "name" : "alice" }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("516541c064fada69cef33ea3"), "name" : "bob", "sister" : { "$ref" : "persons", "$id" : "5165419064fada69cef33ea2" } }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("516541e464fada69cef33ea4"), "name" : "cavin", "sister" : { "$ref" : "persons", "$id" : ObjectId("5165419064fada69cef33ea2") } }
```

Could anybody tell me what's the difference and which way is preferred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is that one is actually an `ObjectId` and the other is a string representation of what looks to be an `ObjectId`.

DBRef as an ObjectId:

```
db.persons.insert({name: 'cavin', 
     sister: new DBRef('persons', 
         new ObjectId('5165419064fada69cef33ea2'))}) // use an ObjectId
```

DBRef as a String:

```
db.persons.insert({name: 'bob', 
     sister: new DBRef('persons', 
        '5165419064fada69cef33ea2')}) // use a string
```

In the example you included, the `ObjectId` format could result in more efficient storage as it's a 12-byte value instead of the 24 bytes that the string representation would require. If you wanted to use `DBRef`s, I'd use an `ObjectId` if the referenced collection is using `ObjectId`s for the `_id`.

You aren't required to use an `ObjectId` in a [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/). It can be any value that represents the key (`_id`) of the related collection/DB.

As the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) suggests, unless you have a compelling reason for using a `DBRef`, use manual references instead.

Answer (score 0):

**ObjectId Pros**

- it has an embedded timestamp in it.
- it's the default Mongo _id type; ubiquitous
- interoperability with other apps and drivers

**ObjectId Cons**

- it's an object, and a little more difficult to manipulate in practice.
- there will be times when you forget to wrap your string in new ObjectId()
- it requires server side object creation to maintain _id uniqueness
- which makes generating them client-side by minimongo problematic

**String Pros**

- developers can create domain specific _id topologies

**String Cons**

- developer has to ensure uniqueness of _ids
- findAndModify() and getNextSequence() queries may be invalidated