# What's the difference between _id: ObjectID and String?

Tags: mongodb

What's the difference between:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea")
}
```

and

```
{
   _id: "507f191e810c19729de860ea"
}
```

I can't seem to find anything on the matter.

It puzzles me because when you insert using JavaScript it'll use the `ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea")` format.
But if you use the C# driver it'll use the `"507f191e810c19729de860ea"` format.

The string format seems like the better choice as it uses less space.

Comment: What do you mean that the C# driver is using the "String" format?

Comment: It might just be a derp :). I'm using `cm.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);` and `ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();` which causes it to be of the latter. Guess I'll try out `ObjectIdGenerator.Instance` next :) - I had a lot of troubles getting it to work, so tried a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ObjectIDs are a 12-byte BSON object ID (it requires 24 to display as hex, since you need two hex characters to encode a byte value). The string is a full 24 bytes. See the [ObjectID specification](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for specifics.

That said, you can use anything you want for your `_id` field, but it's recommended that you stick to a consistent scheme - either use all strings (as well as strings in cases that you reference other documents from foreign keys) or use all ObjectIDs. It is conventional to use ObjectIDs, but as long as you have a fully consistent scheme, you shouldn't have significant problems with it.

Comment: Makes sense. Any chance you know why the C# driver is using the string format instead of the smaller ObjectId?

Comment: No idea, but the driver probably contains an ObjectID factory somewhere that you can use.

Comment: What Christ said is exactly right. In mongo ObjectIDs are a 12-byte BSON object ID that is also based a clock, its almost impossible to have the same object id. for more info: http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

Answer (score 2):

The biggest difference is of course the destination storage and how you interact with it in the API. (I wrote about something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923788/mongodb-construct-dbref-with-string-or-objectid/15927508#15927508) on StackOverflow as it related to DBRefs).

When using the C# driver (and plain-old-C#-objects), if you want to force the Id to be stored as an `ObjectId`, you may need to use the `BsonRepresentationAttribute`:

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you want to keep your classes free of MongoDB attributes:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<StackOverflow>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});
```

I have used this [technique](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#representationserializationoptions) a number of times successfully. When I don't explicitly set the `_id` to a custom ID (a custom key of some sort), I always use the `ObjectId` format as it's relatively small and unique (and is smaller than a UUID and also embeds creation time which is really nice sometimes).