# How to set a linked object property by ObjectId in the Realm Swift SDK

Tags: swift, realm

TLDR: **How can one set a to-one reference object property without initialising the full object?**
e.g. by knowing the ObjectId of the linked object (something like `DBRef` in JS)

---

**Setup:**
Suppose there are two Realm `Object`s: `Dog` and `Person`, that have a to-one-relationship (i.e. each person can have one "linked" dog in the sense described [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/relationships/#define-a-to-one-relationship-property) in the docs).

---

**Question:**
Can I initialise a `Person` instance that has a "to-one" reference ([like this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/relationships/#define-a-to-one-relationship-property)) to a dog **independent** of whether this dog already exists or not? (e.g. by specifying the ObjectId that a dog instance will have in the future, once it is initialised / added to the realm). Of course, this link would point nowhere when this dog does not yet exist.

I realise that normally one would not manually have to use any ObjectId, but simply set the property "dog" of the person object to the instance of "dog". However, this requires the dog instance to exist in memory.

When reading the person object later, one should get either nil if the dog with that ObjectId doesn't exist, but "automatically" get the dog once the dog has been created / added to the realm.

```swift
let realm = try! Realm()
let dogId = ObjectId(string: UUID.uuidString()) // this is all we know about the dog

let person = Person(dogId: dogId) // this should already "point" to the dog with dogId, but of course it is nil, since no dog with this id exists
print(person.dog) // prints nil

let dogBello = Dog(id: dogId) // now, person should instantly point to this when reading with person.dog
print(person.dog) // should print the dogBello instance
```

```swift
class Person: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var objectIdName: ObjectId
    @Persisted var dog: Dog? // set this property by ObjectId of Dog???
    convenience init(ogId: String? = nil) {
        self.init()
        self.objectIdName = ObjectId(string: UUID.uuidString())
        // self.dog = ...?
    }
}
class Dog: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var objectIdName: ObjectId
    @Persisted var dogName: String?

    convenience init(id: String, dogName: String? = nil) {
        self.init()
        self.objectIdName = id
        self.dogName = dogName
    }
}
```

---

**Motivation:**
We have posts and users stored on a server, that get independently sent to clients (as JSON). Each post has one user as a to-one reference property. When a post arrives in the client before the user to that post arrives, we cannot set a link to the user, since it may not exist yet in the client. Searching for posts that "want to" point to a user once the user arrives seems unnecessary, since the post contains an ObjectId that uniquely points to a user already.

---

Outside of swift this seems to be possible, using `DBRef()` ([see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923788/mongodb-construct-dbref-with-string-or-objectid)) by creating the link with a ObjectId or string. Does something like DBRef exist in the Swift SDK?
I found nothing in the relevant docs about this issue.

---

Edit: One workaround I could imagine would be to initialise an empty User with the id stored in the JSON of the post, which gets overwritten once the user object arrives.. but this feels more like a work-around.

Comment: The question is a little confusing (hence my answer). The word 'Linked" has a direct correlation to a feature in Realm but I don't think that's what is meant; I think you mean reference? Also, this *When a post arrives in the client before the user to that post arrives* is not possible; the post has (or should have) a user reference so when the post 'arrives' so will the user reference. The general layout and code flow seems to be doing a lot of manual manipulation of data, which in Realm is generally not needed. e.g. ObjectId's are rarely, if ever, need to be referenced directly.

Comment: Once again sorry, I have yet again updated the question. I have also added some workaround idea that may illustrate the idea further. Yes indeed, I mean reference, or at least what realm docs refer to as "to-one relationship". The problem is that it arrives as JSON, so the form of the reference received from the server is simply a string. It is exactly my question: how can I transform this string into an actual reference in the realm object instance created?

Comment: Great update. It's much more clear now.

Comment: Now that we have some great info in the question. I deleted the old answer and crafted a sparkly new one. Let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to this question - and answer.

- The data is flowing to the app as JSON and can be in any order; person objects my arrive and then later dog objects or vice versa.
- There doesn't appear to be a reason to keep a *placeholder*. When the json data arrives you'll know if the person has a dog or a dog has a person (via a property) and if the respective object doesn't exist, it can be created when that objects data arrives and populated from the json data (keep reading).

Let's start with two models Person and Dog

```
class Person: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id = ""
    var myDogsId: String!
    @Persisted var myDog: Dog?
}

class Dog: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id = ""
    var myPersonsId: String?
    @Persisted var myPerson: Person?
}
```

Notice that the myDogsId and myPersonsId are not managed - they are only used for the decoding process to temporarily hold the id of the respective object to see if it exists.

Here's some sample json data for person and dog - two functions to return the encoded data

```
func getPersonJsonData() -> Data {
    let json = """
{
"_id": "1111",
"myDogsId": "9999"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)

    return json!
}

func getDogJsonData() -> Data {
    let json = """
{
"_id": "9999",
"myPersonsId": "1111"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)

    return json!
}
```

Then the code - it's essentially identical between person and dog

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = getPersonJsonData()
let p = try! decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data)

//first check to ensure this person has a dog
if let maybeId = p.myDogsId {
    //then check if the dog already exists, and if so, create the reference to the existing dog
    if let maybeDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).where({ $0._id == maybeId }).first {
        p.myDog = maybeDog
    }
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(p) //will add the person *or* the person and a reference to the existing dog

    //then if the dog already exists, add a link back to the person
    if let maybeDog = p.myDog {
        maybeDog.myPerson = p
    }
}
```

and then the opposite if a dog json arrives

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = getDogJsonData()
let d = try! decoder.decode(Dog.self, from: data)

//first check to ensure this dog has a person
if let maybeId = d.myPersonsId {
    //then check if the person already exists, and if so, create the reference to the existing person
    if let maybePerson = realm.objects(Person.self).where({ $0._id == maybeId }).first {
        d.myPerson = maybePerson
    }
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(d) //will add the dog *or* the dog and a reference to the existing person

    //then, if the person already exists, add a link back to the dog
    if let maybePerson = d.myPerson {
        maybePerson.myDog = d
    }
}
```

This code tests out:

If there's an existing dog in Realm with _id = 9999 and a person json arrives with _id 1111 and a myDogId of 9999, the person is created, its myDog property is populated with the existing dog reference and the dog object myPerson property is populated with the person.

Same thing if the person object exists and the dog json arrives.

Lastly, if NO data exists and either person or dog arrives first, or in any order thereafter, everything links up correctly.